# Recursively generate script tags for all JavaScript files within a directory with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, file, recursion, tags

I'm building a complex app with lots of JavaScript files in lots of sub-directories. I know I want to include them all (it won't affect performance), but I don't want to manually create a script tag for each. Given that all of my files are children of a "/js" directory, how could I dynamically generate the script tags for each with PHP? Something like this:

```
// first somehow recursively get all .js files, then:
foreach($files as $file) {
  echo '<script src="' . $file->path . '"></script>';
}
```

Comment: You got the answer you were looking for, but I think you're not searching for what you really need. If I guess correctly, your js files are all using each other as dependencies, so the order in which they are included matters. With that in mind, you can see that recursively including scripts based on the directory tree might not work well. You should take a look at solution specifically built for this, like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most elegant way is to use SPL in my opinion.

```
$dirIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path/to/js");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  $dirIterator,
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if($file->getExtension() == 'js') {
      // You probably have to adjust the full path according to your DOC_ROOT
      $url = $file->getPathname();
      echo '<script src="' . $url . '"></script>';
    }
}
```

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php to see what else you can do with `$file` .

Comment: Thanks! I found that I don't even need the $path variable. Just this does the trick: "$url = '/' . $file;"

Comment: The only thing I'm not sure about now is how to add line breaks. All of the script files are put in a big paragraph, which is fine, just not that pretty ...

Comment: add a `\n` at the end of the echoed string.

Comment: Like this? echo '<script src="' . $url . '"></script>\n'; This just echos "\n".